# Drupal 7 "undefined function" fatal error; from FTP error

Tags: 7, commerce

One of the guys here deleted a module folder, in error, from drupal 7 site using FTP (I know but it was a mistake).

the Commerce module was deleted. Now can not access the site at all as we are getting a fatal error
Fatal error: Call to undefined function commerce_pricing_attributes_property_info_callback() in /var/www/sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/modules/field.info.inc on line 30

Anyone know how to correct it?
line 30 is
    $callback($info, $entity_type, $field, $instance, $field_type);

The function in question is below

```
function entity_metadata_field_entity_property_info() {
  $info = array();
  // Loop over all field instances and add them as property.
  foreach (field_info_fields() as $field_name => $field) {
    $field += array('bundles' => array());
    if ($field_type = field_info_field_types($field['type'])) {
      // Add in our default callback as the first one.
      $field_type += array('property_callbacks' => array());
      array_unshift($field_type['property_callbacks'], 'entity_metadata_field_default_property_callback');

      foreach ($field['bundles'] as $entity_type => $bundles) {
        foreach ($bundles as $bundle) {
          $instance = field_info_instance($entity_type, $field_name, $bundle);

          if ($instance && empty($instance['deleted'])) {
            foreach ($field_type['property_callbacks'] as $callback) {
              $callback($info, $entity_type, $field, $instance, $field_type);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $info;
```

Comment: Can't you just upload Commerce module back, using FTP, just like it was deleted?

Comment: Apologies, already did that

Comment: And it did not help?

Comment: Nope, put them back and nothing, rebooted server, flushed caches and still the screen only shows this error.
I can not access the admin screen from the web page, can only access everything now through the server terminal

Comment: Disable commerce related modules from database.. Do take DB Backup before doing any changes... For more info https://drupal.org/node/157632

Comment: New error from 
commerce_pricing_attributes_property_info_callback() - 
to - 
commerce_price_property_info_callback()......

regardless of resolving this or not. Thanks guys, I am always amazed by the amount of time that people take, to help others that they don't even know

Comment: Thanks all:
I don't have the rep points to answer this officially yet.
I figured it out, based on the above assistance. There was one final blocker and that was the field.info.inc file itself. Once I did all the steps above and removed this file everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a backup this is the time to use it.

If not you should:

1. Put your Site in maintenance mode from command line: https://drupal.org/node/590468 or by using Drush: `drush vset maintenance_mode 1`
2. Replace the deleted module with exactly the same version in exactly the same place.
3. Run update.php either from drush: `drush updb` or command line: https://drupal.org/upgrade/running-update-php
4. All *should* be fine.

Please report back if this works or if another solution is found

Comment: I've done the second option and no luck so will just go with a backup. I was trying to avoid it as the work done back to that point was good progress. Ce la vie

Comment: Doing it whilst in maintenance mode **does** make a difference to how the database reacts to changes to the modules so it is worth performing the steps in the order proposed in the answer. Good Luck